# Search SQL Server string for values from another table

Tags: sql-server, substring, udf, patindex

I have a table with column `name` that has random characters before and after the name ie:

**Table A**:

```
  Name
  -----------------
  asd4345JONlkj345
  .;lidDavidlksd$
```

and I have another table in same DB that has the names ie:

**Table B**:

```
 Name
 ------
 David
 Jon
```

This goes on like this for 30k rows or I'd just hardcode something really quick.  I want to search each string in Table A 'Name' column for each value from Table B, and if found return the name in a new column.

I have a feeling this will be a UDF, which is fine, I'm just unsure how to use patindex in this scenario, or if that is even the right approach.

Comment: I don't understand a down vote in less than a min with no explanation why?  how would one even have time to understand the problem in such short amount of time?

Comment: The downvote did not come from me but I am sure it because it is not really clear what you are trying to do here. We can get a general sense but code doesn't work like that. We need actual specifics.

Comment: Here is a great place to start making your question better. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only need the `LIKE` operator for this:

```
select * 
from TableA
inner join TableB on TableA.Name like '%' + TableB.Name + '%'
```

Comment: no need to use like, just = should be ok based on the description.

Comment: @urlreader How would "00000David00000" be matched with "David" using just an = ?

Comment: I did not see 'random characters before and after the name', sorry about that.

Answer (score 1):

```
  select B.Name, A.Name from tableA A inner join join tableB B
  on rtrim(ltrim(B.Name)) like '%' + rtrim(ltrim(A.Name)) + '%'
```